# SimpleCV Error Mavericks

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, terminal, osx-mavericks, simplecv

I have installed SimpleCV using Homebrew and PIL as guided by the SimpleCV Wiki.
After installation I am unable to open SimpleCV shell moreover when I run a Simple HelloWorld program I am getting this error:

> AccessInit: hash collision: 3 for both 1 and 1

Please Help. Thanks in advance.